# git - bash script to automatically reserve merge conflict

Tags: bash, git, versioning, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

My team routinely goes through merge conflicts because of a versioning file being updated on every build. The file is version.txt.

This is where I've got to so far. I only want it to resolve the version.txt conflict by accepting either the current branch version or the incoming branch. When I use the below script, my PRs show as empty which I assume means it has discarded all local changes by using the ours strategy.

I would like the script to keep all local changes–except for the ones causing the conflict, resolve the conflict and push to the current feature branch. What can I do to achieve this?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

FEATURE_BRANCH=$1
DESTINATION_BRANCH=$2
read -p "Would you like to accept incoming or outgoing changes? {in/out}" OP

if [ $OP = "in" ]; then
  MERGE_STRATEGY="Xtheirs"
else
  MERGE_STRATEGY="Xours"
fi
echo "Pulling current branch"
git pull
echo "Checking out current branch"
git checkout $FEATURE_BRANCH
echo "Pulling destination branch"
git pull origin $DESTINATION_BRANCH -${MERGE_STRATEGY} <<-EOF
  :wq #this part is necessary because vim text editor is automatically opened to display a merge message.
EOF
echo "Conflict resolved, pushing back to feature branch"
git push origin $FEATURE_BRANCH
echo "PR ready for merge"
```

Comment: your question being whether your assumption is correct?

Comment: @zzxyz Updated question